# GAE Go — Async datastore API?

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, go

Is there a Go analogue to Python/Java's async datastore APIs? Or can one just use the normal API with the `go` keyword?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no Go equivalent to the Python or Java asynchronous APIs for any AppEngine service.  In fact, the Go standard library has nothing in the standard asynchronous style either.  The reason is that in Go, you write functions using a blocking style and compose them using some basic concurrency primitives based on need.  While you cannot just tack `go` at the beginning of a `dastore.Get` call, it is still relatively straightforward.  Consider the following, contrived example:

```
func loadUser(ctx appengine.Context, name strings) (*User, err) {
  var u User
  var entries []*Entry
  done := make(chan error)

  go func() {
    // Load the main features of the User
    key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "user", name, 0, nil)
    done <- datastore.Get(ctx, key)
  }()

  go func() {
    // Load the entries associated with the user
    q := datastore.NewQuery("entries").Filter("user", name)
    keys, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &entries)
    for i, k := range keys {
      entries[i].key = k
    }
    done <- err
  }()

  success := true
  // Wait for the queries to finish in parallel
  for i := 0; i < 2 /* count the funcs above */; i++ {
    if err := <-done; err != nil {
      ctx.Errorf("loaduser: %s", err)
      success = false
    }
  }
  if !success {
    return
  }

  // maybe more stuff here
}
```

This same approach can be used in pretty much any context in which you need to run more than one thing that might take awhile at the same time, whether it's a datastore call, urlfetch, file load, etc.

Comment: How does this work given that Go apps on GAE run on a single thread?

Comment: The Go runtime multiplexes many goroutines onto a single operating system thread.  In fact, the default even outside of AppEngine is GOMAXPROCS=1, which means that only one goroutine will be actively running your code.  Despite this, however, the runtime will swap back and forth between goroutines when they communicate, block, execute a syscall, or wait on a lock.

Comment: Thanks. So is there even a performance benefit if they're running on a single thread? Pardon my ignorance.

Edit: I guess that the performance benefit will come from Go executing code while it's waiting for the I/O call to return?

Comment: Exactly.  The runtime swaps back and forth so that there is always something running if there is anything to run.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit API for async in Go. You should use go routines instead. I haven't seen any source on this, but I suspect the async API isn't there because of how easy it is to use go routines.